# Django Rest Serializer validate gives Invalid pk

Tags: python, django, django-serializer

I have this situation:
Model Handling

```
class Handling(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Active', 'Active'),
            ('Archived', 'Archived'),
            )
    entdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    extdate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    kpallet = models.ForeignKey(Pallet, related_name='kpallet', null=True, on_delete= models.PROTECT)
    kitem = models.ForeignKey(Item,related_name='kitems', null=True, on_delete= models.PROTECT, limit_choices_to={'kstatus': 'Active'})
    quantity = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True)
    kstatus = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    def __str__(self):
     return str(self.kpallet)
```

Model Item:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    STATUS = (
            ('Active', 'Active'),
            ('Disabled', 'Disabled'),
            ('Archived', 'Archived'),
            )
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    kdimension = models.ForeignKey(Dimension, null=True, on_delete= models.PROTECT)
    kclient = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, on_delete= models.PROTECT)
    kstatus = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, choices=STATUS)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializer:

```
class HandlingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Handling
        fields = '__all__'
```

Api:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
def handlingCreate(request):
    serializer = HandlingSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
    else:
        print(serializer.errors);
        return Response("Error Handling not created")
    return Response("Handling Created")
```

I get this error and i don't understand how to move on:

```
{'kitem': [ErrorDetail(string='Invalid pk "958c2fd2-bbb6-42d6-8bfe-fbe035e9ceb5" - object does not exist.', code='does_not_exist')]}
```

I've checked the pk and the object exists so I don't understand where the issue could be.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: include the full traceback in your post.

Comment: can you show the definition of the `Item` model?

Comment: Is Item 958c2fd2-bbb6-42d6-8bfe-fbe035e9ceb5's kstatus is Active?

Answer (score 0):

#### use pk_field=UUIDField for [PrimaryKeyRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield)

```
class HandlingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    kitem = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Item.objects.all(), pk_field=UUIDField(format='hex'))
    class Meta:
        model = Handling
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: NameError: name 'PrimaryKeyRelatedField' is not defined

Comment: Prefix serialized.

Comment: Why is this needed when the UUID _is_ valid and the object _does_ exist?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed thanks to Blackdoor for the input.
This is the correct serializer:

```
class HandlingSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
kitem = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Item.objects.all(), pk_field=serializers.UUIDField(format='hex_verbose'))

    class Meta:
        model = Handling
        fields = '__all__'
```